# .C() function from spatstat.geom package not available in R, although it is exported by useDynLib

Tags: r, c, package, namespaces

The CRAN R-package spatstat.geom defines a bunch of .C functions, and exports them in the NAMESPACE file via

`useDynLib(spatstat.geom, .registration=TRUE, .fixes="SG_")`

Yet I cannot access these functions with the usual .C syntax. For instance, the nncross.ppp() function contains a call to

`.C(SG_knnXinterface, ..., PACKAGE = "spatstat.geom")`,

which obviously works inside the spatstat.geom, but not outside of it, unlike for other functions exporting their C-functions in apparently the same way. My questions are:

1. How can I access these C-functions from the console?
2. Is this related to the "nested" package structure of the spatstat.* packages?

I tried to call

`.C(SG_knnXinterface, ..., PACKAGE = "spatstat.geom")`

but it returned

`Error in .C("SG_nnXinterface", PACKAGE = "spatstat.geom", 2) :  "SG_nnXinterface" not available for .C() for package "spatstat.geom"`,

even though I would expect the C function to be accessible in this way.

Some minimal reproducible examples:

Works (or at least function is found)

`.C("spline_value", PACKAGE = "cobs")`

Does not work

`.C("SG_nnXinterface", PACKAGE = "spatstat.geom")`

My sessionInfo():

```
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_BE.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=de_BE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_BE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=de_BE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: Europe/Amsterdam
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] spatstat.geom_3.2-7.007 spatstat.data_3.0-4    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.2       deldir_2.0-2         Matrix_1.6-5         spatstat.utils_3.0-4
[5] tools_4.3.2          grid_4.3.2           polyclip_1.10-6      lattice_0.22-5
```

Comment: Those objects are not usually exported from the package. You can get them with `spatstat.geom:::SG_knnXinterface` for example and use that in the call to `.C()`. It would be easier to verify if you provided a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick I have added an example. Adding the ::: did not help, I guess since these are C-functions.

Comment: When I run `.C(spatstat.geom:::SG_knnXinterface, PACKAGE = "spatstat.geom")` I get `Incorrect number of arguments (0), expecting 15 for 'knnXinterface'`. It sounds like it's finding the function but you are not passing in the parameters it requires. Are you actually trying to call these functions?

Comment: @MrFlick That is interesting. I know the number of arguments is wrong, sorry for not clarifying that. The point is that I do not even get that far, I just get `"spatstat.geom:::SG_nnXinterface" not available for .C() for package "spatstat.geom"` when using `.C("spatstat.geom:::SG_knnXinterface", PACKAGE = "spatstat.geom")`, and when omitting the quotation marks (`.C(spatstat.geom:::SG_knnXinterface, PACKAGE = "spatstat.geom")`) I get `Error: object 'SG_knnXinterface' not found`? I have added my sessionInfo() too.

Comment: I have re-installed the package and now it works as you say, many thanks!

Comment: @MrFlick Still I do not understand why .C("spline_value", PACKAGE = "cobs") works (after loading the cobs package), but .C("SG_nnXinterface", PACKAGE = "spatstat.geom") does not, and the ::: is needed. The only difference in the namespace I can see is the .fixes argument in useDynLoad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about "native registration" of entry points, a relatively new feature of R. The `spatstat` packages use native registration, while package `cobs` apparently does not.

The namespace declaration

```
UseDynLib(spatstat.geom, registration=TRUE, fixes="SG_")
```

tells the package loader to dynamically load the object file `spatstat.geom.so`, and (because `registration=TRUE`) to look for a C function called `R_spatstat_geom_init` which the author of `spatstat.geom` must have written. The loader executes this function, which effectively declares all the available C or C++ functions to the R system, associating their string names with their actual entry points in the compiled object code, and declaring the number and type of arguments. Then for each declared C or C++ function, the loader will create a "symbol" in the R language associated with it. Because a prefix `"SG_"` was specified, the function `nnXinterface` defined in the C code will be associated with a symbol `SG_nnXinterface`. There are **no quotes** around the symbol. The symbol is added to the namespace of the package.

If you wanted to use the R command `.C` to execute the function `nnXinterface`, you need to get access to the **symbol** `SG_nnXinterface`. The symbols are not exported from the package, but they are there in ghe namespace, e.g.

```
spatstat.geom:::SG_nnXinterface
```

will return some information. I'm not sure how to access these symbols in a way that will be acceptable to the R package checker. It will certainly require that `spatstat.geom` is already loaded.

If you want to call the C function `nnXinterface` from some other C code, then you could either (a) just copy the source code for `nnXinterface` into your own package, or (b) figure out how to access the source code from another package, which again may run into issues with the package checker.